# Attach EBS Volume to Windows EC2 with Powershell

Tags: powershell, amazon-ec2

I've seen a lot of questions answered about adding EBS volumes Linux, but not Windows. Say you've discovered that your disk is running low on space (maybe via CloudWatch) and want to add another EBS volume. Can this be done with Powershell?

I'd prefer not to use diskpart.exe since it's more difficult to parse its results (not being a native Powershell command).

Comment: not familiar with the exact cmdlets but I know that amazon provides the ability to actually add/create the volume via powershell, beyond that you would just need to format the disk, which you can do with the [Win32_Volume](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390432(v=vs.85).aspx) WMI class

Comment: Thanks @MikeGaruccio. I've figured something out and posted an answer, but I will be checking out your link.

Comment: Ahh looks like your using some of the newer cmdlets, definitely the way to go if your machines support them, WMI would be a useful fallback if any of your systems are older than 2012.

Comment: yeah, hadn't considered older machines, but this seems to be working for me... thanks @MikeGaruccio

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hoping this helps someone out there. The AWS stuff was easy, but took me a while to track down all the things for Windows to use it.

This answer is stripped down for brevity, so make sure:

1. you've handled the AWS Powershell API exceptions
2. your volumes are "available" before to try to attach them to an EC2
3. the volume shows "in-use" once you've attached it

2 and 3 can be done via the `Get-EC2Volume` API.

Create the EBS Volume:

```
$volume = New-EC2Volume -Size $sizeInGB -AvailabilityZone $az -VolumeType $vType
```

Attach the Volume to the EC2:

```
Add-EC2Volume -InstanceId $toInstanceId -VolumeId $volume.Id -Device $devId -Region $region
```

Windows side:

locate the ebs volume you just attached

```
$diskNumber = (Get-Disk | ? { 
    ($_.OperationalStatus -eq "Offline") -and ($_."PartitionStyle" -eq "RAW") }).Number
```

initialize the disk

```
Initialize-Disk -Number $diskNumber -PartitionStyle "MBR"
```

create max-space partition, assign drive letter, make "active"

```
$part = New-Partition -DiskNumber $diskNumber -UseMaximumSize -IsActive -AssignDriveLetter
```

format the new drive

```
Format-Volume -DriveLetter $part.DriveLetter -Confirm:$FALSE
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Great! I used this answer to create the following script that I use within a user_data script: https://gist.github.com/anderssonjohan/fa88e6ddf883fd161698caac68912394 It's used with terraform but it's just a normal user_data init script so it can be used without terraform as well.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without formatting it?  i want to attach a volume that has data on it that i do not want to lose.

Comment: @Donuts did you figure out any way to do it, I am exactly stuck at the same point. Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: @Deepak i did get this to work.  Here's what i did `Get-Volume | Where-Object FileSystem -Eq "" | Format-Volume -FileSystem NTFS -NewFileSystemLabel "Data" -Confirm:$false;`

Comment: Is there any AWS API to achieve the same? or sdk