# Terraform Vs Packer connection for remote-exec provisioner

Tags: terraform, packer, winrm

I have a **Terraform** infrastructure where I have to install a **Windows 10** server **EC2 instance** with an additional volume (`D:`).

The **Terraform** configuration is quite easy and well explained in [volume_attachment](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/volume_attachment) documentation.

To init, attach and format the new volume I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41384463/4690946), I tested it (by hands) and it works as expected.

The problem is how to automate everything: the `aws_volume_attachment` depends on `aws_instance` so I can't run the script to init, attach and format the new volume in the `user_data` section of the `aws_instance` since the `aws_volume_attachment` is not yet created by **Terraform**.

I'm trying to execute the script with a `null_resource`.

To configure the instance image with **Packer** I'm using `WinRM` with following configuration:

```
source "amazon-ebs" "windows" {
  ami_name       = var.image_name
  communicator   = "winrm"
  instance_type  = "t2.micro"
  user_data_file = "setup.txt"
  winrm_insecure = true
  winrm_port     = 5986
  winrm_use_ssl  = true
  winrm_username = "Administrator"
```

so I tried to replicate the same `connection` for the `null_resource` in **Terraform**:

```
resource "null_resource" "it" {
  depends_on = [aws_volume_attachment.it]
  triggers   = { instance_id = local.jenkins_build_win.id, volume_id = aws_ebs_volume.it.id }

  connection {
    host     = local.jenkins_build_win.fqdn
    https    = true
    insecure = true
    password = local.jenkins_build_win.password
    port     = 5986
    type     = "winrm"
    user     = "Administrator"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "Initialize-Disk -Number 1 -PartitionStyle MBR",
      "$part = New-Partition -DiskNumber 1 -UseMaximumSize -IsActive -AssignDriveLetter",
      "Format-Volume -DriveLetter $part.DriveLetter -Confirm:$FALSE"
    ]
  }
}
```

`local.jenkins_build_win.fqdn` and `local.jenkins_build_win.password` resolve correctly (I wrote them with a `local_file` resource and I can use them to connect to the instance with **Remote Desktop**), but **Terraform** can't connect to the instance. :(

Running **Terraform** with `TF_LOG=trace` the only detail I can get for the error is:

```
[DEBUG] connecting to remote shell using WinRM
[ERROR] error creating shell: unknown error Post "https://{fqdn}:5986/wsman": read tcp {local_ip}:44538->{remote_ip}:5986: read: connection reset by peer
```

while running **Packer** with `PACKER_LOG=1` I can't get any details on **WinRM** connection: my intention was to compare the calls made by **Packer** with the ones done by **Terraform** to try to identify the problem...

I feel I'm stuck. :( Any idea?

Comment: The EBS builder for Packer has this argument: https://www.packer.io/plugins/builders/amazon/ebs#launch_block_device_mappings. Have you considered this, and would it fit your use case sufficiently?

Comment: Thank you @MattSchuchard ; I didn't know that option, anyway I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51494091/4690946), `ebs_block_device` works better for me as I need to configure volume size at **Terraform** time; moreover it seems to use lesser amount of resources (1 less snapshot). Anyway I'll leave the question open as `WinRM` could be helpful for many other stuff.